# Unexpected token in jsdom when run npm build

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a next.js app and on "npm run build" i get the following error

```
> Build error occurred
/var/www/directoryname/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/parser/html.js:170
    after._pushedOnStackOfOpenElements?.();

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

node version: v12.22.5
next.js version: v12.1.6

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using optional chaining syntax which is not supported on Node 12. Upgrade to at least Node 14 to get the syntactical support.